# JavaFx - Is it possible to implement Drag-and-drop of GUI elements?

Tags: drag-and-drop, javafx

I would like to drag button from one VBox to another.. is it possible to do that with JavaFx 2.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what I was looking for.
To get source object I'm using event.getGestureSource() method...
All I need to do is add this object to target

```
target.getChildren().add(event.getGestureSource());
```